# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::passengers()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I want to seed my db that shows me this error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::passengers()

this is databse seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    factory(App\Airport::class, 5)->create();
    factory(App\Flight::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($flight) {
        factory(App\Customer::class, 100)->make()->each(function ($customer) use ($flight) {
            $flight->passengers()->save($customer);
        });
    });
}
```

### Customer Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function Flights()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

### Flight Model

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    //
    public function arrivalAirport(){
        return $this->belongsto('App\Airport','arrivalAirport_id');
    }
    public function departureAirport(){
        return $this->belongsto('App\Airport','departureAirport');
    }
    public function passenger(){
        return $this->belongsto('App\Customer','flight_customer');
    }
}
```

who know where this can come ?

Comment: Please can you show the code for your `Flight` model?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes of course . i edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the singular in your model and trying to access the plural in the seeder.

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    public function passengers()
    {
        return $this->belongsto('App\Customer', 'flight_customer');
    }
}
```

Comment: so exactly what should i do. could you give me a hand?

Comment: It's right there. You either rename the method of the passengers model to `passengers` or the method you're using in the seeder to `passenger`.